# microsoft.extensions.configuration .Net framework 4.7 migration

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, .net-standard-2.0

microsoft.extensions.configuration  in a cross platform solution for handling configuration .
But trying to use it in already exists .net framework projects is not straight forward , so any advise will be helpful .

The extensions library can't work with app.config and web.config because :

1. In extensions xml provider there must be 'name' attribute to distinguish between same element tags
   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers), and in .net framework config files there are many duplications (app.config for example contains many 'add' elements without name attribute , in many sections)
2. In extensions xml provider they throw exception in case of namespace (like in runtime element there is xlmns , https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47018)

Also we have schema for using config files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/) and in .net standard there is no schema, so I'm not sure how to convert our files to appsetting.json or appsetting.xml (for example what to do with the runtime element that nuget manager is adding to app.config and what to do with system.web ...).

So I have tried keep using the same config files and configured custom xmlConfigurationProvider class
that use System.ConfigurationManager to add appsettings keys , and also remove runtime,appSettings,configSections from the stream, but I don't think its the right approach because I need to ignore many sections in web.config and manipulate the stream that the xmlConfigurationProvider class is using.

So please share your knowledge how did you used  microsoft.extensions.configuration in .net framework with backward compatibility ?

Comment: app.config isn't the format expected by the XML configuration provider. The best approach is to create a custom provider to inject settings from ConfigurationManager. In your custom provider, you can filter the section.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/ ?

Comment: Are you using Net 4.7.2 (or later)?  Net 4.7.2 allow just setting target to a different version of framework without changing any source according to the documentation.  Not sure if it really works.  There were bugs with 4.7.0 and 4.7.1 that got fixed in 4.7.2.

Comment: @JesúsLópez , no , the point is to start working with microsoft.extensions.configuration

Comment: @Vernou this is what I have started to do , but it means to filter many sections , this means I need to go over all element in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/ and filter all sections with namespace or duplicate elements ? is this the right approach ?

Comment: This is the approach I used temporarily, the time to convert app.config to appsettings.json. Which is the best will depend on your scenario.